# Using selenium Python to iterate on different elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My problem is while my loop iterate just one time , and I wanna go through all elements that I listed , if you have any suggestion that can helps .
Here's my code  , you can test it it's working , so if you can suggest me any methods to switch windows , I tried `driver.back()` , but it didnt solve my problem

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd

options = Options()

# Creating our dictionary
# all_services = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Profil', 'Motif', 'Questions', 'Reponses'])

Testing = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Motif', 'Resultat'])

path = "C:/Users/Al4D1N/Documents/ChromeDriver_webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

# we are going to visit all profils procedures
# for profil in ['particuliers','professionnels','associations']:
#     driver.get(f"https://www.demarches.interieur.gouv.fr/{profil}/accueil-{profil}")

driver.get("https://www.demarches.interieur.gouv.fr/associations/accueil-associations")
sleep(3)
# Get all first elements in bodyFiche id which contains all procedures for associations profile
list_of_services = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("liste-sous-menu")
for service in list_of_services:
    # In each element, select the tags
    # atags = service.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
    atags = service.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[starts-with(@id,'summary')]/a")
    for atag in atags:
        # In each atag, select the href
        href = atag.get_attribute('href')
        # Open a new window
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        # Switch to the new window and open URL
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get(href)
        sleep(3)
        # we are now on the second link
        # Get all links in the iterated element
        list_of_services2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("content")
        for service2 in list_of_services2:
            atags2 = service2.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
            for atag2 in atags2:
                href = atag2.get_attribute('href')
                driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
                driver.get(href)
                sleep(3)
               
        # Close the tab with URL B
        driver.close()
        # Switch back to the first tab with URL A
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

driver.close()
Testing.to_excel('Limit_Testing.xlsx', index=False)
```

How can I go through the links that I get , with a `driver` method , because running it like that , It just iterate on one element and it goes back to the first link mentioned in `driver.get(url)` (the first one)

Comment: Can you please be more specific, and try and scope down your code to where your problem is? (atm I'm not sure which loop you think of)

Comment: It's about the last loop `for service4` , what I want to get , is going back to the previous loop that has different links and iterate on it , but I don't see how can I solve it , by `driver.switch_to.window()` , so my program stop when I do first iteration of the last loop mentioned below

Comment: I see, you're trying to write a crawler. If it is not a javascript-based page, it looks like your problem could be better solved with `scrapy` ( https://scrapy.org/ ) where you don't even need to run selenium and you'll have an easy time crawling subpages.

Comment: Yeah I know , but I did with `selenium` on other websites , but here my main issue is switching my window , I didnt find a solution for that

Comment: I have no idea about that, sorry:( If you try and focus your question on that, maybe with 3 lines of essential code - the one where you open the new window and the other where you try and close it, could attract more people to solve your problem. (also you could fix your title to reflect this)